# How to solve "App crash" error in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

We run a video server on nodejs in heroku. Occasionaly our app crashes.The same url opens once and next time it doesn't. We have Papertrail add-on hooked to it.It shows "app crash" errors and "Connection closed without response" errors.These are some of the errors what we get once in a while.

```
Nov 11 02:06:08 XXXXXXXX heroku/router: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/media/556e108442577c030072a109" host=www.xxxxxx.co request_id=46779cd1-507f-4252-b8ac-79c250556869 fwd="5.218.182.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https 
Nov 11 02:06:33 XXXXXXXX heroku/router: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/media/556e108442577c030072a109" host=www.xxxxxx.co request_id=b648c1c4-55db-403a-b5e6-702516d0d61d fwd="5.218.182.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https 
Nov 11 02:06:38 XXXXXXXX heroku/router: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/media/548ee10dbb2ac502000f2ccf" host=www.xxxxxx.co  request_id=e5b7923f-dae7-4344-a3a6-8e1b3f1468b6 fwd="84.201.133.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http 
Nov 11 02:06:44 XXXXXXXX heroku/router: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/media/556e108442577c030072a109" host=www.xxxxxx.co request_id=91c67bf8-0f34-4df1-b152-fc94a9c52a75 fwd="5.121.70.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https 
Nov 11 02:07:38 XXXXXXXX heroku/router: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/media/548ee10dbb2ac502000f2ccf" host=www.xxxxxx.co  request_id=58979771-eb0d-463e-b942-0ffdba4b125f fwd="84.201.133.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http 
Nov 11 02:07:42 XXXXXXXX heroku/router: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/media/59e5d55c20e0cd0400c85aa1" host=www.xxxxxx.co request_id=f82b8377-32e9-48d5-bc02-f0cdfc300b5c fwd="157.55.39.84" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https 
Nov 11 02:07:47 XXXXXXXX heroku/router: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/js/mediaelement-flash-video.swf" host=www.xxxxxx.co  request_id=5f83f33f-0bed-4ab5-80a2-847546f57052 fwd="207.46.13.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https 
Nov 11 02:19:54 XXXXXXXX heroku/router: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/media/5a05dea5c450b804002e0d04" host=www.xxxxxx.co  request_id=7ee98386-95f2-4979-83b5-00288fad959d fwd="66.249.66.1" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https 
Nov 11 08:21:22 XXXXXXXX heroku/router: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/media/5a05dea5c450b804002e0d04" host=www.xxxxxx.co  request_id=27f8511b-3084-4022-aedf-474f3aa75231 fwd="66.249.66.18" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https 
Nov 11 10:04:30 XXXXXXXX heroku/router: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/media/5a05dea5c450b804002e0d04" host=www.xxxxxx.co  request_id=b2d644d8-2eed-4d57-9e20-35d61c0c9b3f fwd="66.249.66.1" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=24ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

This is a secondary server (just serves videos to our main server) so it wont have much load (I think).Its not like it causing total system crash but,I am being cautious because website involves money.

Does this happens usually?Should I make any changes to my dyno? anything that make these errors not to appear (atleast for the same url).

same url example:https://www.heroukuapp.com/media/548ee10dbb2ac502000f2ccf

the above wont open any proper url.because `"www.heroukuapp.com"` is dummy

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason for these errors. This has to do with my code in nodejs app.

If someone getting the same errors. If they had log handler installed a plugin in heroku (for me its papertrail). These errors come in a bunch. If some unhandled error occurs in nodejs app, the app crashes in heroku. and trail of errors continues until the app is restarted. To know the cause of the problem go to point in logs at which the app crashed occurred for the first time. There you find the error and cause for this trail.